# Are speeches by Heads of States academic sources?

Tags: research-process, citations

I'm uncertain whether speeches by Heads of State or other governmental figures are academic sources? Can someone please clarify?

Comment: We want you to flesh out your question.  Give us some context: why are you asking?  How will you use the answers?    What purpose do you want to use the source for?  Give us your thoughts: what makes you think they would or wouldn't be a source?  What do you mean by an "academic" source?  What research have you done?  We expect you to do some research before asking.  Any record that others could review is a "source".  It's a different question whether it is reliable, or credible, or accurate, or useful.

Answer (score 32):

A speech by a head of state is a [primary source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_source) and can be used and cited as such:

> Abraham Lincoln's Gettysburg Address begins "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent a new nation" [Lincoln, 1863]

It is not a peer reviewed scientific document, however, and should not be used in that way:

> The United States was founded in 1776 [Lincoln, 1863].

That's a very easy way to get things wrong, because speeches by heads of state are generally used for political effect, not for delivering factual information.  For example, if you used Lincoln as a citation, you'd be rather misled, because the United States per se did not exist until [the adoption of the constitution in 1789](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States#Independence_and_expansion).

Comment: There were the Articles of Confederation before then, but you could argue the nation didn't completely exist until the early 1780's.

Comment: +1 for citing Lincoln as the source for when the U.S. was founded. :) However, the last sentence probably depends on how you define "the United States." Its present government didn't exist until the Constitution was ratified, but it _was_ an independent country since 1776. Arguing that that the U.S. didn't exist until 1789 would be like arguing France didn't exist until 1958.

Comment: @reirab, Panzercrisis: You affirm my point nicely: a head of state like Lincoln just needs to convey a point to an audience.  A scientific discussion needs to have clear and well-grounded definitions, (e.g. how do the fuzzy notions of "founding" and "nation" relate to the lengthy process of developing a new state).

Comment: Don't you need to cite a source for the claim that Lincoln said those words? See the Wikipedia article on the address, specifically [Text of the Gettysburg Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettysburg_Address#Text_of_Gettysburg_Address). More generally, the claim that a head of state said something should be backed by some reference supporting it.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan That is a fair point: I wrote my answer assuming that the person was actually getting the text of the speech directly in some way, but if the observation is not direct, then it's not a primary source and should be cited to the actual place where the information has been obtained instead.  For example, writing "Art thou the King of the Jews?" [Pilate, 30] would *definitely* be incorrect, and the quote should be sourced to the King James Version of the bible instead.

Answer (score 10):

Speeches by public officials, and especially heads of state, are historical documents, as they often crystallize and clarify political priorities, justify policy decisions and set the tone and direction for action.

Thus I would not call speeches by heads of state "academic" sources, in the sense that they are neither written and delivered by academics, nor are they intended for academic audiences or purposes.

As @jakebeal points out, they are not peer reviewed, nor are intended to be, in the same way as are academic publications.

However, in certain disciplines, especially history, political science, and communication/media studies/PR, they are probably widely used and considered acceptable primary sources that can be tapped for citations to support academic arguments (e.g. political positioning, rhetoric, or persuasive strategies).

Answer (score 0):

If President Obama says, in a public speech, that the Riemann Hypothesis is true, then this is sufficient backing for writing, in an academic paper, that "President Obama said that the Riemann Hypothesis is true."  It is not sufficient backing for writing "The Riemann Hypothesis is true."

This has nothing to do with his being a head of state.  The preceding paragraph would remain correct if you replace both occurrences of "President Obama" with "Miley Cyrus."